# Links clickable but only opening when <right mouse button, open in new window>

Tags: html, hyperlink

I made a website using a bootstrap for a school project. The only problem is. You can click on my links. But they wont open on left click. I've tried everything, even my webdesign teacher can't help.

http://go-ao2eu.webhosting.be/5info/ortwin/

I've searched about this on the web but the only thing I found was something with javascript interfering. I've searched for javascript traces in the html and disabled them. Didn't fix my problem... Thanks for the time... :)

Comment: Which link doesn't open? they all seem to work

Comment: This seems to be a script/event handler problem, yes. But that amount of scripts don’t magically find their way into a page by themselves, and especially http://go-ao2eu.webhosting.be/5info/ortwin/js/script.js looks rather self-written (or at least copy&pasted together from several different other sources, to implement a couple of effects) – so why are you embedding this, if you don’t seem to have a clue of what it actually does?

Comment: The links work, but not on left click (like a normal link should). And this is a bootstrap. I didn't write any of the code except some of the html5. 
Using a bootstrap was a part of the assignment. Should I just use another bootstrap? My classmates didn't have any of these problems..